# Can one app change the settings of another app?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

Is it possible for one Android application to modify the settings of another application?

Say, I want to create an app that temporarily blocks notification from all other apps. Is it even possible?

I can see from the official [documentations](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html) that all apps run in their own sandbox. But I wanted to know if there are any workarounds for this.

The other use case I had in mind was to create an app which could migrate all the apps from phone memory to SD card memory.

Both of them require tweaking settings of other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can touch another app's setting, is using root.
Unless the destination app gave you the option to do so, using intent maybe or an API.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as you said in question , each app runs in their own sandbox . If it is possible , people would have hacked all apps .